# How to make pre/code tags wrap taking up full height of container?

Tags: html, css

I am displaying some raw HTML code on my website using `pre` and `code` tags. However, I would like to change it so that the code wraps and fills up the entire container's height rather than being a single line with `overflow:auto`.

How can I accomplish that?

```css
.code-container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 800px;
  background: #e6e6e6;
}

pre {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="code-container">
    <pre><code>&lt;img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=512x512&zoom=12&center=Chicago&format=png&style=feature:road.highway%7Celement:geometry%7Cvisibility:simplified%7Ccolor:0xc280e9&style=feature:transit.line%7Cvisibility:simplified%7Ccolor:0xbababa&style=feature:road.highway%7Celement:labels.text.stroke%7Cvisibility:on%7Ccolor:0xb06eba&style=feature:road.highway%7Celement:labels.text.fill%7Cvisibility:on%7Ccolor:0xffffff&key=YOUR_API_KEY /&gt;</code></pre>
</div>
```

Comment: remove `pre` or use `white-space: normal;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add white-space and word-break properties to pre + 100% height for the overflow to work.

```
pre {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: normal;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```